# Is there a way to provide validation set to scikit SGDClassifier explicitly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am new to [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) package. I wonder if is it possible to give the validation set to SGDClassifier's fit model ? I have some models that are not implemented in scikit and I want to use the same validation set that I used for non-scikit implemented models with the scikit models.

I check the prototype:

```
class sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss=’hinge’, penalty=’l2’, alpha=0.0001, l1_ratio=0.15, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None, tol=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, epsilon=0.1, n_jobs=None, random_state=None, learning_rate=’optimal’, eta0=0.0, power_t=0.5, early_stopping=False, validation_fraction=0.1, n_iter_no_change=5, class_weight=None, warm_start=False, average=False, n_iter=None)[source]
```

I could not find any argument for it but I just wanted to ask here too.

Comment: Parent abstract class has `_make_validation_split` method, but I don't see how you can access it https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L272